# PHP adding to array in while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I'm having some trouble adding to an array during a while loop and was wondering if any of you could help me.  Firstly, some background.  I am looping through some sql results and trying to gather the results while grouping by various ids to make it easier to deal with later.  It just seems to be one line of code that isn't working.  There is some code below

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
if(!array_key_exists($row['foreign_key_value'],$contacts)){
    $contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']]=array();
}
if(!array_key_exists($row['uid'],$contacts['foreign_key_value'])){
    $contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']][$row['uid']]=array();
}
$contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']][$row['uid']][$row['rating_id']]=$row['rating_value'];  

}
```

It is the last line I am having trouble with, where I am adding rating_id and rating_value.  The data I am looping through is 4 fields - foreign_key_value, uid, rating_id and rating_value.  The structure I want to end up with looks like

```
array(1) {
  [73]=>
  array(2) {
    [9]=>
    array(1) {
      [4]=>
      string(1) "3"
    }
  [1762]=>
    array(1) {
      [1]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
  }
```

I just cannot get the rating_id and rating_value to create more than one key value pair in the last array, where I am expecting 5 pairs.  The only thing I am getting is the last pair selected.  I really have no idea why I'm not getting the data I need, can anyone help?

abc667 - you're spot on.  Thank you very much.  I've been staring at it so long I missed that and I'm starting to feel like an idiot now

Comment: Should `$contacts['foreign_key_value']` in your first code section, line 5 be `$contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']]`?

Comment: change `$contacts['foreign_key_value']` to `$contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']]` in `if(!array_key_exists($row['uid'],$contacts['foreign_key_value']))`

Comment: abc667 - you're spot on.  Thank you very much.  I've been staring at it so long I missed that and I'm starting to feel like an idiot now

Comment: passerby you're on it as well - I would vote you both up if I could

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the $contacts array BEFORE the while() loop - so you can use it afterwards

```
$contacts = array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
if(!array_key_exists($row['foreign_key_value'],$contacts)){
    $contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']]=array();
}
if(!array_key_exists($row['uid'],$contacts['foreign_key_value'])){
    $contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']][$row['uid']]=array();
}
$contacts[$row['foreign_key_value']][$row['uid']][$row['rating_id']]=$row['rating_value'];  

}
```

Comment: The $contacts array has already been declared, i just didn't include it in the code